# Serial communication library RXTX

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

I'm looking for serial communication library RXTX in Google and can't find theirs official site. Are they gone? Where is place I could download RXTX lib and get some tutorials?

Comment: google might be your friend:https://github.com/rxtx/rxtx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe their official site is down. I recently downloaded java RxTx here:

http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/r/Downloadrxtx22jar.htm - jar file containing RxTx library
http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/r/Downloadrxtxnativewindowsjar.htm - windows drivers

As for tutorials, google is your friend. Here is one link I found with a quick google search:
http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/10/17/serial-communication-in-java-with-raspberry-pi-and-rxtx/
The API doc for javax.comm (which RxTx implements) will be useful if you are just starting out:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/package-summary.html